# Issue with SQL query when using DISTINCT and ORDER BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Given a database table named Messages with the following columns:-

```
MessageID, FromUser, ToUser, Message, DateTime
```

I want to write an SQL query which selects the distinct values for the "FromUser" column, but I would also like the values ordered by DateTime.

Essentially, a query such as:

```
SELECT * FROM Messages WHERE ToUser='1' ORDER BY DateTime DESC
```

And then, to select the distinct FromUser with something such as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT FromUser FROM Messages WHERE ToUser='1'
```

At the same time, maintaining the ordering from the previous query.

I have tried using a nested query and ran into an issue as you're unable to use ORDER BY in the inner query.

Essentially, I want the syntax for the query to represent (this is invalid but...):

```
SELECT DISTINCT FromUser FROM Messages WHERE ToUser=1 AND FromUser IN 
(SELECT * FROM Messages WHERE ToUser=1 ORDER BY DateTime DESC)
```

Comment: There can be multiple candidate dates for each unique FromUser so you need some aggregation... which single date do you want, the max() ?

Comment: The problem here is what if FromUser appears multiple times in the `Messages` table with different times.  Where should they appear in the list?

Comment: I'm trying to find the reasoning for your desired output. If you post some bogus data and expected output, I'll most likely get a quick response here.

Comment: @rs - Your query doesn't work (tried previously), as it can't order by DateTime when DateTime isn't in the select statement.

Comment: @AlexK. - Yep, I want to select the maximum value for date.

Comment: Essentially, the messages table represents an inbox, so when a user on the front end views their inbox, it would show a unique message thread from each user they have interacted with, ordered by the most recent interaction at the top of the page.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that this is what you need:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [FromUser] ORDER BY [DateTime] DESC) RN
    FROM [Messages]
    WHERE ToUser='1' 
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

So include `DateTime` in your `select` statement, either grouping by it, or using one of the aggregate functions, such as `MAX()`, like:

```
    Select fromuser, datetime
    from messages
    where touser = '1'
    group by 
    fromuser, datetime
    order by 
    fromuser, datetime
```

or

```
Select fromuser, max(datetime) as max_datetime
from messages
where touser = '1'
group by 
fromuser
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have multiple timestamps for each FromUser.  I am going to assume that you want to use the last timestamp for each of them.

```
select * 
from Messages join 
    (select fromuser, MAX(datetime) as lastdate from Messages
    group by FromUser) as abb1 on abb1.FromUser = messages.FromUser and abb1.lastdate = messages.Datetime
where ToUser = '1'
order by Datetime desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Messages].[FromUser] FROM (
SELECT [FromUser] as [FromUser], MAX(DateTime) as [Date]
FROM [Messages]
GROUP BY [FromUser]) as [Messages]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way;

```
select * from
(
    select *, max(DateTime) over (partition by FromUser) newest
    from Messages
) T
where DateTime = newest
```

(n rows if there are identical dates for the same person)